# How to test an extension in PupeteerSharp headless mode?

Tags: c#, puppeteer, puppeteer-sharp

Here is an article describing how to test an extension in PuppeteerSharp:
https://www.puppeteersharp.com/examples/ChromeExtension.html

The problem here is that it requires `headless` option to be set to `false`. If I set it to `true`, extension just stops being loaded.

I need a headless mode to be set to true, because I'm trying to run some automated tests in Docker container which doesn't have an x-server that can be used to display a browser window.

I suspect it might be possible to do, as [official Puppeteer docs say](https://pptr.dev/guides/chrome-extensions):

> Extensions in Chrome/Chromium currently only work in non-headless mode and experimental Chrome headless mode.

Do you know how to enable experimental headless mode in Chrome when using PupeteerSharp?